# Locust.io send requests at an exact rate

Tags: locust

Is there a way in locust.io to set the rate at which the requests will be sent? I am using locust to see how my database will perform under increased load. I am not interested in the max request rate the database can take but rather the performance of the database when it receives a specific rate. For example I want to see the latency of the read operations under a specific write load.

Answer (score 2):

I think You need to set min_rate and max_rate at the same value:

```
class MyUser(MyLocustExtendedClass):
    host = "myhost"
    min_wait = __VALUE__
    max_wait = __VALUE__
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to set locust to a specific RPS, also check reply on this post: [specifying RPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713104/locust-io-controlling-the-request-per-second-parameter)

But you can attempt to reach a specific number with using this formula:

```
rps = wait time X #_users
```

Change wait time in the Locust class and number of users