# Inconsistent results from locust

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, locust

I am running a locust test against my integration environment, which is hosted on a Lambda function behind API Gateway. When I run the test, the results seem to vary from about 1-3 requests per second, to 20-30 requests per second. The variation itself is unpredictable--the timing of the tests in relation to each other, etc., does not seem to affect the outcome. The error rate is nearly 0 after each test, and I am not editing anything between runs. Would very much appreciate any input on what might be happening!

Comment: can you add your script?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your issue is similar to the one described here: [Locust.io: Controlling the request per second parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713104/locust-io-controlling-the-request-per-second-parameter)

And it's, well, by design of the Locust itself.